# Custom order by in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table in which there are 3 fields

```
+------+------+------+
| name | type | rank |
+------+------+------+
| abc  | A    | 1    |
| def  | B    | 1    |
| ghi  | A    | 2    |
| jkl  | C    | null |
| mno  | B    | 2    |
| pqr  | C    | 1    |
+------+------+------+
```

How to sort this table first by type (A then B then C) then by rank  in ascending order?So that rank with null comes after rank> 0?

Comment: SELECT * from table ORDER BY type, rank ASC;

Comment: null is coming above the numbered data and i need it at last

Comment: select & sort where rank is not null, then union with a select where rank is null

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` expressions in the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY type
        ,CASE WHEN rank IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ,rank
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1004/1/0)

You could also use:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY type
        ,COALESCE(rank,999999)
```

But then you have to pick a number the field can never be higher than, the first method eliminates that guesswork.